# display: table-cell, border-spacing don't work with buttons?

Tags: html, css, button, input, css-tables

So, I'm using `display: table-cell` to put two buttons next to each other so that if text from one overflows to the next line, both buttons are the same height. I have `border-collapse: separate` and am using `border-spacing` to put space between them. It works just fine if I'm using something like `<div class="button">`, but as soon as I use the `<button>` element, the middle space disappears.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uASbb/


Now, using the `<div>` is fine for now (if not semantically as accurate), so I'm mostly just curious if anyone knows what exactly is going on here.

Note: I've also noticed some (different) weird behavior with using `<input>` elements in this same situation: http://jsfiddle.net/G5SFX/1/


Is `display: table-cell` just not supported in these instances? Is this a bug?


Thanks!

EDIT: It seems like you just can't apply a `display: table-cell` to a button; it just defaults back to `inline-block`. See this screenshot from Chrome WebInspector: 

[image: table-cell -> inline-block]


Now the questions remain: Is this intentional? Is it the specification or is it just the browser? Can we get it changed?

Comment: Interesting... And it wouldn't be necessary to have `width:50%`, but with the buttons it doesn't work either. Comparison: http://jsfiddle.net/uASbb/1/

Comment: i dont know its is bug or not for tag "button", but if see in firebug`s "DOM" we gets next : for tag "button" offsetLeft = 0 , for tag "div" offsetLeft = 15...

Comment: Not quite a solution, but something to consider is nesting a div or span inside the button.

Comment: Yeah, what I ended up doing was having an outer `<div>` to take care of the spacing and an inner `<button>` to be semantically correct. It's not as elegant as I would like, but hey, that's web design.

Comment: It works well when using Opera 12 (but not in Chromium of Firefox), so I guess this is some kind of browser bug. But on the other hand – do you really need to format the buttons as table-cells? What about floats or `display: inline-block;`?

Comment: The idea behind formatting them as table-cells was that they would all auto-expand together if the text in one became too long to be on one line. That way you avoid having an awkward button that's larger than the others.

Comment: I consider it a bug, but probably in the spec more now than browser implementations (which kind-of previously defined the spec anyway).  `button` is a 'replaced element' which means normal rules don't apply - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38779191/2511031 and that thread.

Answer (score 2):

Inserting the `button` element into a `div` is a good solution (in your place I would have choose it, too), but if you want to display both `button` elements side by side with space in between without the help from a `div` you can try this for your `.item` class:

```
.item {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 46%;
    background: aliceBlue;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 1%;
}
```

`Width` is reduced to `46%` to allow a `margin` of `1%` around every `button` element. You have a space between them now, and also if you resize the window the second `button` element won't fall under the first one.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/codenighter/H7TZU/

Hope it helps.

EDIT: It seems that `border-spacing` (in fact none of `block` styling is working) doesn't work with `button` or `input`. But it does working with other inline elements like `span`, `h1` or `b`. So, for `input` and `button` the `display: table-cell` property can't be properly applied (I've changed the `width` value for `button` and `input` and it showed, while for `span` and `b` the `width` remained actually at 50%).

Examples: http://jsfiddle.net/codenighter/HrTZS/

Comment: The first example leaves me at least with a much larger space on the right-hand side.

Comment: Adding extra layers of elements with well-defined classes to allow better styling is good practice in IMO, though it was a bit frowned upon back in 2012 (when the situation was much worse).  Nowadays with so much usage of 3rd-party libraries it is essential for such to be flexible.  Nothing worse than dealing with markup you can't modify (except for death and taxes).