# How to center tab bar

Tags: html, css, tabs

I solved my last problem and now my new question. I trying to make own tab bar (or navigation bar, name how you need). I found many questions here about that, but I don't get really ok answer. So, this is my code:

```css
div.tab {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#FEFEFE, #F1F1F1);
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border-color: #DEDEDE;
}

div.tab button {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    background: inherit;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #DEDEDE;
    outline: none;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    text-align: center;
    /*left: 50%;*/
}

div.tab button:hover {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#6C6B6C, #686869);
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #636263;
    outline: none;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFC;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #FFFFFC;
}

div.tab button.active {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#6C6B6C, #686869);
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #636263;
    outline: none;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFC;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #FFFFFC;
}

.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    -webkit-animation: fadeEffect 1s;
    animation: fadeEffect 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeEffect {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeEffect {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Home')">Home</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Subscriptions')">Subscriptions</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Friends')">Friends</button>
    <button class="tablinks" disabled>System Appearance</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Settings')">Settings</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Problem, what I have is just a center tabs. If I use  is working, but Tab Bar is ending on the end of the page. I need for ending on the last tab. So, what I gonna do? (And, if you can answer one more question, then how to round not only tab bar, just watch on picture)

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDmBh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the `tab div` to not take up the complete width of the parent by setting it's `display` css property to `inline-block`

Then center this by using `text-align: center` on the parent div. I've added a new wrapper `div.tab-container` so that you don't have to center everything in your `body`

For your second problem, adjusting the radius makes it less visible if that helps.

```css
div.tab {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#FEFEFE, #F1F1F1);
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border-color: #DEDEDE;
    display: inline-block;
}

div.tab-container {
    text-align: center;
}

div.tab button {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    background: inherit;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #DEDEDE;
    outline: none;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    text-align: center;
    /*left: 50%;*/
}

div.tab button:hover {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#6C6B6C, #686869);
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #636263;
    outline: none;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFC;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #FFFFFC;
}

div.tab button.active {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#6C6B6C, #686869);
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #636263;
    outline: none;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFC;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #FFFFFC;
}

.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    -webkit-animation: fadeEffect 1s;
    animation: fadeEffect 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeEffect {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeEffect {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="tab-container">
  <div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Home')">Home</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Subscriptions')">Subscriptions</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Friends')">Friends</button>
    <button class="tablinks" disabled>System Appearance</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Settings')">Settings</button>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Wow, it's really helped me. Very big thanks to you :3

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the header end at the last button you just need to remove the `overflow:auto` line and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use another element instead `<button>`, and add display: table on parent element, and table-cell on child elements.

About `<button>`: [display:table-cell not working on button element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37444481/displaytable-cell-not-working-on-button-element)

```css
div.tab {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#FEFEFE, #F1F1F1);
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border-color: #DEDEDE;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

div.tab div {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    background: inherit;
    position: relative;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #DEDEDE;
    outline: none;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
    /*left: 50%;*/

}

div.tab div:hover {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#6C6B6C, #686869);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #636263;
    outline: none;
    color: #FFFFFC;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #FFFFFC;
}

div.tab div.active {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#6C6B6C, #686869);
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #636263;
    outline: none;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFC;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #FFFFFC;
}

.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    -webkit-animation: fadeEffect 1s;
    animation: fadeEffect 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeEffect {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeEffect {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="tab">
    <div class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Home')">Home</div>
    <div class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Subscriptions')">Subscriptions</div>
    <div class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Friends')">Friends</div>
    <div class="tablinks" disabled>System Appearance</div>
    <div class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Settings')">Settings</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Using a div element for a tab it's unusually for me now, but thanks for an advance.