# List of Replaced Elements

Tags: html

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8012297/1318265) and other places online, "replaced elements" that have special properties are referenced, usually citing examples of `<img>` tags, `<svg>` tags and the like.  However, I'm trying to style some elements that are the output of a third-party library that I'm not in control of and I would like to know **exactly** what elements I can and can't use pseudo elements like `:before` and `:after` on.

Even [the actual documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/conform.html#replaced-element) on replaced elements doesn't have an exact list.  Which elements are "replaced"?

Comment: [If you want to know HTML details, you're looking at the wrong spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#replaced-elements). That said, there are other categories of elements other than replaced elements that disallow `:before` and `:after`.

Comment: It appears that ability to use pseudo elements on elements doesn't strictly correspond with their formal classification of any kind. For example, all browsers now allow using them with the `hr` element, which is void element (even the styling of the W3C specs themselves uses this!). Also, most browsers allow pseudos for `img` that wasn't loaded, and Opera Presto allowed them for nearly everything.

Answer (score 7):

You are looking for the wrong spec.

**Replaced elements** are those, whose content will be replaced in the document preparation phase. Before the replacement happens, browser (or officially, user agent) could not know the exact dimensions. For example, the content of `img` element will be replaced with the image defined as its `src` attribute. And only after replaced, browser could know how wide and high it is, then try to render it in the right position.

Please note that, **even `:before` and `:after` could be a replaced element**, depending on the `content` property defined in CSS.

I've seen a lot of times people get confused with **replaced elements** and **void elements**, because the replaced elements we use the most, such as `img` and `input`, are also void elements. **Void elements** are actually what you should look for.

Quote from the [w3c spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#void-element):

> A void element is an element whose content model never allows it to have contents under any circumstances. Void elements can have attributes.

The **contents** stated in above quote mean both elements and pseudo elements, in markup, not rendered document.

The following is a complete list of the void elements in HTML:

> - `area`, `base`, `br`, `col`, `command`, `embed`, `hr`, `img`, `input`, `keygen`, `link`, `meta`, `param`, `source`, `track`, `wbr`

It's easy to determine whether an element is void or not - all void elements are self-closed, all non-void elements must have an end tag.

Comment: Why downvote? Was my answer wrong, or did I misunderstand the post?

Comment: "all void elements are self-closed, all non-void elements must have an end tag" is a bit oversimplified. There is no such thing as "self-closing" element in HTML (unlike X(HT)ML and SVG). It's true that void elements never have a closing tag, but there are non-void elements with optional closing tags (in which case they are closed implicitly).

Answer (score 5):

In `html`, *Replaced Elements* are those which refer to content which already possesses intrinsic dimensions:

**List of Replaced Elements:**

- `<applet>`
- `<audio>`
- `<br>`
- `<button>`
- `<canvas>`
- `<embed>`
- `<iframe>`
- `<img>`
- `<input>`
- `<math>`
- `<object>`
- `<select>`
- `<svg>`
- `<textarea>`
- `<video>`

Comment: It appears you're missing `<select>`, in addition to any hidden elements like `<meta>` and `<link>`.

Comment: Thanks, @zzzzBov, I've added `select` to the list above.

Comment: @zzzzBov how are `<meta>` and `<link>` considered replaced elements?

Comment: @zer00ne, they're not, but the question states "I would like to know **exactly** what elements I can and can't use pseudo elements like :before and :after on." which set `<link>` and `<meta>` are included in.

Comment: @zzzzBov I see, OP really needs a list of voids to avoid when using `:before/:after{content:..}`.

Comment: Where did you get this list from?

Comment: Very late but: this is not correct, the spec *explicitly* excludes `input` elements like `select` from the list of replaced components. They instead call them "widgets": https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#widgets